# Accessibility and selecting range of dates

Tags: widget, accessibility, wai-aria

[image: range datepicker]

I have no idea what sound tips should be when blind person interact with 
range datepicker. Could someone help me?

upd: I just wonder to know what is expected for accessible range date picker

Comment: Can you please clarify the focus of your question? Do you want to know if any accessible data pickers already exist? Do you want to test the one you have? Do you want to know the recommended keyboard commands for data pickers? How to implement an accessible date picker? Something else?

Comment: I just wonder to know what is expected for accessible range date picker

Answer (score 0):

Datepickers are not inherently accessible, but they can be used with some caution and a bit of modification.

First off, I would recommend against trying to do both start and end date from a single datepicker, unless you really know what you're doing with regard to accessibility. I'm not saying that it can't work, but you may have to do considerable development and testing to get it to work well enough.

Instead, I would suggest having two separate input fields: one for the start date and another for the end date. Then for your datepicker, take a look at this tutorial:

https://dequeuniversity.com/library/aria/date-pickers/sf-date-picker

The techniques described here are a little older, but they should still work just fine in jQuery 3.